# Is there currently lighting on the market that can simulate sunlight?

Tags: lighting

During northern winter I always wish I had lighting powerful enough to simulate sun shining in my window (or from my ceiling). Are there currently products on the market powerful enough to do so?

I'm using 1500Lm LED lamps with a 2700k color rating, but they're very much far from what sunlight looks like.

Comment: Powerful enough: no. You need absurd amounts of power to approach the brightness of sunlight (100,000 Lm). You can however get lighting that replicates the spectrum of sunlight, which is more important.

Comment: VTC - This is an off topic shopping question.

Comment: @Hobbes it's reachable. two 400W HPS lights will give you that many lumens.  So will 32 T8 tubes.  That's eight 4-lamp 2x4 troffers, or 6 if they are 6-lamp.

Comment: Answers posted so far are weak.  You need office style lighting, which is Very Bright compared to traditional home lighting.  A single 6-lamp T8 fixture is *twice as bright* as that dangerous 500W halogen, and you can get fluorescent tubes cheaply in 5000-6500K and high CRI, which does a better job emulating the sun.  Talk the people who do office or better the "indoor horticulture" people doing grow lighting, they put a staggering amount of light in small spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look for lighting solutions used to treat Seasonal Affective Disorder (SAD).

### Desktop Panels

> The theory behind conventional Full Spectrum (White Light) light boxes is that they effectively replicate sunshine. As a result they give the user a positive response when they are lacking sunshine.

- [Buying a SAD light](http://www.sad.org.uk/buying-a-sad-light/)

---

### Bulbs

There are also replacement lightbulbs that claim to have similar purposes

> 6 watt LED R50 E27 ES Edison screw globe bulbs with opal cover
>   DAYLIGHT WHITE SUITABLE FOR SAD Sufferers 
>   480 lumen, daylight white 6400k, 30000 hour bulbs

6400K is obviously higher than 2700K

Of course, 480 lumens is very little, You'd need a ceiling fixture that can take many E27 bulbs.

There are 800 lumen E27 bulbs and higher output bulbs in T8 tube format etc.

search for ["full spectrum" "seasonal affective disorder" light bulb](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22full+spectrum%22+%22seasonal+affective+disorder%22+light+bulb)

Comment: This looks great, but most look like they're handheld lamps for direct exposure. Are there solutions to install on the wall/ceiling to provide lighting for an entire house?

Comment: @JonathanReez: answer updated.

Comment: Though I cant find a reputable source to link ATM, effective treatment for SAD is more about brightness than spectrum.  Newer ones are not always full spectrum, the main requirement is that they put out about 10000 lux.

Comment: @Grant I'd be great to have 10000 Lux panels covering the whole ceiling, but I can't seem to find any manufacturers of such powerful lighting

Answer (score 0):

If it's Seasonal Affective Disorder you are trying to cure, see a doctor.  Light therapy can work, but needs to be managed properly.

I suspect part of your problem is not the color spectrum, but brightness.  I've noticed in the winter everything seems so much darker - part of that is replacing all the 100w light bulbs with 40 or 60w equivelent LED bulbs.  They don't put out nearly as much light.

If you just want to make your room bright again for awhile, the cheapest way is halogen work lights with T3 halogen bulbs.  I use them in my office for a couple hours a day and it's wonderfully bright.  They put out a lot of heat as well, which is fine in the winter.  I found I was fine with the yellowish light (same as any old incandescent bulb) as long as it made the room nice and bright.

You can get 500w halogen work lights for under $20 that put out 8000 lumens.  Ten times what a 60w LED bulbs puts out.

There are similar permanent fixtures (though usually only for up to 200w bulbs) you can install.  I used to have one above the bathroom mirror which was wonderful.  This isn't a very power efficient option, but if you are only using it an hour or two a day it won't make that big a difference.